# C# Function return instance of type Interface with Generic Types

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following:

```
    public interface IInput
    {
    }

    public interface IOutput
    {
    }

    public interface IProvider<Tin, Tout>
        where Tin : IInput
        where Tout : IOutput
    {
    }

    public class Input : IInput
    {
    }

    public class Output : IOutput
    {

    }

    public class Provider : IProvider<Input, Output>
    {

    }
```

I would like to be able to get the following method to cast the result:

```
private static IProvider<IInput, IOutput> GetProvider()
{
    return new Provider();
}
```

I know the types are different but they implement the interfaces.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get this to work is if `IProvider` is covariant in its generic properties.

```
public interface IProvider<out Tin, out Tout>
    where Tin : IInput
    where Tout : IOutput
{
}
```

Doing that gets rid of your compiler error for your example code, but because you did not show what you are doing with `Tin` and `Tout` inside `IProvider` I can't say if it will give you other compiler errors or not.

The reason you must declare it covariant to be able to use it as a parameter is you could potentially bad things if it was not. Here is a simplified example to show how it could go wrong:

```
public interface IAnimal { }

public class Dog : IAnimal { }

public class Cat : IAnimal { }

public interface IAnimalCollection<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
{
    TAnimal GetAnimal(int i);
    int AddAnimal(TAnimal animal);
}

public class DogCollection : IAnimalCollection<Dog>
{
    private List<Dog> _dogs = new List<Dog>();

    public Dog GetAnimal(int i)
    {
        return _dogs[i];
    }

    public int AddAnimal(Dog animal)
    {
        _dogs.Add(animal);
        return _dogs.Count - 1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAnimalCollection<IAnimal> animalCollection = GetDogCollection();

        animalCollection.AddAnimal(new Cat()); //We just added a cat to a collection of dogs.
    }

    private static IAnimalCollection<IAnimal> GetDogCollection()
    {
        return new DogCollection();
    }
}
```

If we where allowed to return a `DogCollection` as a `IAnimalCollection<IAnimal>` that makes adding a `Cat` perfectly legal due to it being a `IAnimal` and `AddAnimal` would be `int AddAnimal(IAnimal)`.

By adding `out` this makes the `AddAnimal` method illegal, but now it is perfectly safe to say "This collection of dogs is represented as a collection of animals" because now there is no way to add to the collection an animal that is not a dog.

---

To make the above code compile, you must make one of two tradeoffs. Either make `GetDogCollection()` not return a interface and delete the addition of the cat.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAnimalCollection<IAnimal> animalCollection = GetDogCollection();

        //animalCollection.AddAnimal(new Cat()); //Would get a compiler error if we tried to add a cat to the collection
    }

    private static IAnimalCollection<Dog> GetDogCollection()
    {
        return new DogCollection();
    }
}
```

Or make the interface covariant, but to do that you would need to delete the `AddAnimal` method from the interface, which also would not let you add a cat to the collection.

```
public interface IAnimalCollection<out TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
{
    TAnimal GetAnimal(int i);
    //int AddAnimal(TAnimal animal); //Can't have methods that take in the type when using "out"
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAnimalCollection<IAnimal> animalCollection = GetDogCollection();

        //animalCollection.AddAnimal(new Cat()); //Would get a compiler error because this method no longer exists.
    }

    private static IAnimalCollection<IAnimal> GetDogCollection()
    {
        return new DogCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works almost. It can cast that way. However, I have to remove the following Method from IProvider : Tout GetOutput(Tin input);

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer He is not using a factory method, [it works if you are explicitly stating the interfaces instead of leaving them generic](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2JXwP).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, I see. BTW, for me, then OP approach to generics sounds bad, because if you use generics, you want an instance of `IProvider<T, S>` and not T, S as interfaces..

Comment: @Baral yes, like I tried to explain in the 2nd half of my answer, if you want to do what you are trying to do the tradeoff is you cant have any methods or properties that "Take in" that generic type.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I copied/paste the code and it is not compiling. because of the Cast exception. Adding "out" fix the issue but breaks the AddAnimal method : Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleInterface.DogCollection' to 'ConsoleInterface.IAnimalCollection<ConsoleInterface.IAnimal>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Baral see my updated answer to address that. You must choose one of two changes to make the code compile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take the risk of explaining you an alternate approach.

Maybe I'm mistaken. It seems like you're looking to create provider instances using a factory method that will be somewhere else.

If you go this way, you can't avoid an explicit cast here:

```
private static IProvider<IInput, IOutput> GetProvider()
{
    // Explicit upcast
    return (IProvider<IInput, IOuput>)new Provider();
}
```

*Some suggestion: common naming scheme for generic parameters is a capital `T` and a pascal-cased identifier like `TOutput`*.

You need this cast because C# compiler knows that `TOutput` must implement `IOutput`, and `TInput` must implement `IInput` thanks to generic constraints, and even when `Provider` has given generic arguments that full-fills the whole constraints, **the problem comes when the factory method can't implicitly prove that generic parameters `TOutput`/`TInput` for `Provider` class are the same as ones given to the factory method itself**:

```
public static IProvider<TInput, TOutput> GetProvider<TInput, TOutput>()
    where TInput : IInput 
    where TOutput : IOutput
{
    // Hey!!!!!!!! Do TOutput and TInput of this method are the same as 
    // Provider TOutput and TInput? Who knows, thus, compiler error:
    // Cannot implicitly convert type 'Provider' to 'IProvider<TInput,TOutput>'. 
    // An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
    return new Provider();
}
```

[Check this working sample in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y6Zn7b).